# Printing to pdf file with 100.00 resolution blurs in gimp

Tags: pdf, gimp

I open a pdf page in gimp, and make some change to it. Later when I print it to a pdf file with 100.00 resolution in both X and Y axis, the result is a bit but obviously blurred.

When I specify a resolution higher than 100.00, the image will shrink according to how much bigger the specified resolution is than 100.00.

I wonder if I can print to a pdf file without blurring or shrinking? Thanks!

Comment: When you read the image into gimp, you should be able to specify a resolution afor it to use when it rasterizes the file. Specifying a bigger number there as well as when you print should minimize both blurring and shrinking. That's how I do it with Photoshop anyway.

Answer (score -1):

From another poster, this worked for a map I was needing to print:

(1) In Image | Scale Image, set Interpolation to None and change the X and Y resolution. You will see that the Image Size in pixels doesn't change. Hit Scale, and the image will have the new resolution.

(2) Go back into Image | Scale Image. Set Interpolation to Cubic. This time, change the Image Size to be what you want in inches or cm. GIMP will compute the resulting pixel resolution and resample the image.

And to further enhance, I'd suggest

(3) Go into filters, choose Enhance, and apply sharpen